# Não consigo utilizar acentos no output do console

Tags: c++

Estou tentando utilizar o "é" porém o console mostra "Ú"
estou utilizando \u00E9 para mostrar "é"

#include 
using namespace std;

int porcentagem(float p, float p2) {

```
return ((p / 100) * p2);
```

}

int main() {
float a;
float b;

```
cin >> a; 
cout << a << "% de "; cin >> b; cout << " \u00E9 igual a: " << porcentagem(a, b) << "\n\n";







/*float a;
float b;
cin >> a;
cout << "% de ";
cin >> b; cout << "equivale a ";
cout << (a / 100.00f) * b << "\n\n";
*/

system("pause");
```

}

Comment: Existe erros, deve  prestar mais atenção em fontes confiaveis... não tem **#include using namespace std;** o namespace é apenas uma chamada e não precisa do include para ele... para usar o **setlocale** realmente precisa usar include dessa maneira **#include <locale.h>** e dentro do main **setlocale(LC_ALL,"");** as aspas dupla sem nenhum argumento dentro...Indica que vai pegar a linguagem do teus sistema .. caso teu sistema estiver **pt-br** contrario pode passar para ele explicitamente.

Answer (score -2):

olá!
quando for incluir os arquivos cabeçalhos.
use o #include .
Dentro da função main(), use digite: setlocale(LC_ALL,"ptb")

ex: #include 
#include 
using namespace std;
int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"ptb");

return 0;
}